# How to calculate the Expected Value of |X-Y| where X and Y are two independent Unif (0, 1)?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to calculate E|X-Y|, and I am wondering how this could be done for uniform random variables with the distribution Unif(0, 1).

I want to construct a new RV Z = X - Y, but I am not sure about the distribution of it. Also, how should I deal with the absolute value here?

Comment: Hint for one possible approach: using symmetry of $|x-y|$ in $x$ and $y$, we have $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |x-y|dydx = 2 \int_0^1 \int_0^x |x-y| dydx = 2\int_0^1 \int_0^x ydydx$$

Comment: Where does the 2 at the front come from?

Comment: You can either draw a picture or read Gono's response below.

Comment: What part are you not sure about?

Answer (score 0):

A usual way to handle an absolut value is to split it up to the two cases where the argument is greater $0$ or less then $0$. Hence

$$|X - Y| = |X-Y|1_{X - Y \ge 0} + |X-Y|1_{X - Y \le 0} = (X-Y) 1_{X \ge Y} + (Y-X)1_{Y \ge X}$$

Now Shalops comment is based on the fact, that by a symmetry argument $(X-Y) 1_{X \ge Y}$ and $(Y-X)1_{Y \ge X}$ have the same distribution hence:

$$E[|X - Y|] = 2E\left[(X-Y) 1_{X \ge Y}\right]$$

But ofc you can also solve it "by hand" by just calculating $E[(X-Y) 1_{X \ge Y}]$ and $E[(Y-X)1_{Y \ge X}]$ directly.

But as you said you are actually interested in the distribution of $Z = X-Y$ but those you also can calculate directly by having:

$$P(Z\le z) = P( X - Y \le z) = \int_0^1 \int_0^{(z+y) \wedge 1} dx dy$$